# How do I prevent my Mac from resetting the software update download every time i resume it?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software

I've  had this problem before too but I couldn't find a concrete resolution. I'm running Yosemite 10.10.2 with the latest version being 10.10.5. Since I've had some wireless connectivity issues with the present version, I thought it would be wise enough to install the latest version and see if the issue has been totally dealt with. But every time I resume the download (since the whole package is some 2.36 GB), the Appstore resets it to around 50 MB and all that was downloaded goes to waste. Now I want some advice on how to stop this annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [OS X 10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832). Combo updates [contain all previous updates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/80657/45492).