# macOS Sierra update can't be installed on this disk.This volume does not meet the requirements for this update

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update

I have been updating the macOS from 10.12.4 to 10.12.6 . For this I have downloaded the macOS dmg file from the Apple website. But when I go on for installing the macOS then I see this error.

[image: Screenshot: Install macOS Sierra Update]

I have around 100GB of space but its still not updating the OS. What should I do about it. I need to install "Xcode" from the App Store but when I go on for installing it gives me the error that it needs the OS update to be 10.12.6 How can I fix this up?

The version I am working on is 10.12.4
[image: Screenshot: Mac info]

Comment: Which update exactly did you download? Was it the ["Update"](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1930?locale=en_GB), which would probably fail, or the ["Combo Update"](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931?locale=en_GB), which would probably work? (See this question for the difference: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80657/what-is-a-combo-update-and-how-is-it-different-than-the-regular-update )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, downloading and installing the [Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) sometimes works when the Delta update fails. Please edit your question to indicate the specific Mac model you are working with.

Comment: Hi, you can check above the version.

Comment: I am upgrading el capitan from 10.11 to 10.12 tried combo update still same issues

Comment: @shikher.mishra what did you do ? how did worked for you

Comment: I just did the things mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: This answer is in a frustrating state. Ran into the same issue, *with* combo. Asking this again will be a duplicate despite no solution here? What *are* the requirements?

Answer (score 7):

I just bought a reconditioned MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and as I wanted to upgrade to macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, I ran into the same problem. I tried everything and was about to give up, until I stumbled the following page:

- https://technology.siprep.org/waiting-for-filevault-encryption-to-finish-to-install-macos-updates/

and realized that FileVault was still encrypting my hard disk and that was blocking any macOS update.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for this, also your laptop needs to be on adapter power for the encryption to keep running. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In very simple words. You need update .dmg file which is COMBO.

Apple has 2 types of updates Delta and Combo.
Delta. You can only update Version +1. Ex . If you have 10.15.2 and you download 10.15.5, Mac will provide this error but it will allow if you download 10.15.3.

Combo. It contains all delta + new update and you can download and install without an issue. Delta kind of check doesnt apply for combo

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the full installer, I would make a bootable USB installer if you have a spare 8 GB drive lying around.

- [How do I make a bootable USB flash drive a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-a-mac)

Search Apple or this site for the [createinstallmedia](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-yosemite-or-mavericks-install-usb-flash-drive) command that you can run from the command line (terminal.app) and make the full installer into a bootable image.

Then restart with the USB and hold option key. This works when your system isn’t bootable at all and much better than just a combo updater or the install app on your main OS.